# How to replace the \\ in a given string with empty?

Tags: strings

How to replace the "`\\`" in a given string with empty?, such as for any given string "how `\\` are `\\` you" in a latex code, we want to get how are you, how to achiever this?

Comment: Are you willing and able to consider a LuaLateX-based solution?

Comment: pdflatex or latex compile mode, thank you very much@Mico

Comment: You probably want to replace ``\\`` and the possible spaces surrounding it with a single space, I guess.

Comment: locally `\renewcommand\\{\unskip\ \ignorespaces}` but better in most cases would be to not have `\\ ` in the source. What is your real use case here?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thank you very much, it really works, since there is a newline command "\\" in the header of  the page, so I need to replace the "\\" with empty to make it show normal

Comment: but why is there a  `\\ ` in the page header? There is not one by default so you are adding one you don't want, then removing it?

Comment: some times, we need to underline the title and add a \\  to produce a newline and the page header refers to the title, thus we need, such as   \title{Learning and teaching for the \\young children} when make the title it will produce two lines with underline, but in the  page header  we need to remove the "\\"

Answer (score 1):

Dr. David Carlisle's suggestion works perfectly, renew the newline command `\\` and apply it in a local environment.

```
{\renewcommand\\{\unskip\ignorespaces} he\\llo}
```

instead of showing

```
he
llo
```

, it will show `hello`